# Change Label for Telephone on Checkout Page

Tags: forms, magento-community, ce-1.9.0.0

I would like to know where can I edit the label for the form under "Billing Information" One page Checkout?

Comment: It depends upon your theme and configuration, add some more details to the question so others can understand what exactly you are after and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change label "`Telephone`" only on billing, you can edit below file.

```
app/design/frontend/[THEME_PACKAGE]/[THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

To change label "`Telephone`" on checkout page, you can use below file.

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv
```

Try using template path hints to checkout the file path if you are not using default Magento OnePageCheckout.